# Make item bigger without bumping other items in html

Tags: html

I got commissioned to edit https://nosociety.net/ and I need to make WIKI FORUMS and SHOP bigger on hover without bumping each other, how can I do it?

Current code:

```
css: .items { display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; -ms-flex-pack: distribute; justify-content: space-around; -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100px; flex-basis: 100px; padding: 18px 0 10px 0; } HTML:
<div class="items">
    <a href="wiki" class="item forums">
        <div>

            <p class="subtitle">search the</p>
            <p style="color:#98212a" class="title">ᴡɪᴋɪ</p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="forums" class="item store">
        <div>
            <p class="subtitle">visit the</p>
            <p style="color:#98212a" class="title">ғᴏʀᴜᴍs</p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="shop" class="item vote">
        <div>
            <p class="subtitle">browse the</p>
            <p style="color:#98212a" class="title">sʜᴏᴘ</p>
        </div>

    </a>

</div>
JS
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').on('mouseenter', function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: "+=10",
                    height: "+=20"
                });
            })
            .on('mouseleave', function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: "-=10",
                    height: "-=20"
                });
            })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't need JavaScript to do this.

Try something like this in `CSS`:

```css
a.item:hover .title {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transform-origin: left;
```